# How to use JWT with custom state-provider in Api-Platform?

Tags: api-platform.com

In my Symfony app, I've added Api-Platform, and I'm using a custom state provider, since my data lives in an external Soap application.

I've been asked to implement JWT authentication.

Once authenticated, I need to pass the user's credentials on every Soap-request. What is the recommended approach to accomplish this?

The StateProvider's `provide()` method is called automatically upon resource request. How do I make it aware of the JWT?

Comment: You can write your own access_handler: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/access-token-authenticator